# How to return the values of shiny inputs from module, process on these inputs in main app and send the information to module for output?

Tags: r, module, shiny

I am trying to take the values of shiny inputs from module, process on these values and send the information to module for output but I am facing problem to access the values of these inputs and also they are not working as reactive(means as soon as the user change the value of any input, modules should be called automatically and show the desirable output.

As of now, I am able to create the UIs through modules but not able to access the input values and use them in the main app for calculation/processing and send the desired output for the module.

```
**app.R**

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bs4Dash)
source("test.R")

N = bs4DashNavbar()

S = bs4DashSidebar()

C = bs4DashControlbar()

B <- bs4DashBody(fluidRow(column(6,boxplus_UI(id = "boxplus1",tit = "box1"))))

ui <- bs4DashPage(title = "Demo",navbar = N,sidebar = S,controlbar = C,body = B)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  callModule(boxplus_ftr_creation,"boxplus1",ftrs = list(list("Filter1","dropdownlist",
             c("option1","option2","option3"),NULL),list("Filter2","groupbutton",c("option1","option2","option3"),"option1")))
  ftrs_selected_vals  <- reactive({
    Vals <- callModule(boxplus_ftr_vals,"boxplus1",ftrs_name = list("Filter1","filter2"))
    mess <- NULL
    mess <- paste0(Vals()[[1]][[1]]," : ",Vals()[[1]][[2]]," and ",Vals()[[2]][[1]]," : ",Vals()[[2]][[2]])
    mess
  })
  callModule(boxplus_output,"boxplus1",info = ftrs_selected_vals())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


**test.R**

boxplus_UI <- function(id,tit = "Untitle",st = "success")

{
  ns <- NS(id)
  bs4Card(title = tit,status = st,width = 12,collapsible = TRUE,closable = TRUE,solidHeader = FALSE,headerBorder = TRUE,
            uiOutput(ns("filters")),
            textOutput(ns("main_body")))
}

boxplus_ftr_creation <- function(input,output,session,ftrs = NULL){

  output$filters <- renderUI(
    if(!is.null(ftrs)){
      fluidRow(
        lapply(1:(length(ftrs)), function(i){
          if(ftrs[[i]][[2]] == "dropdownlist"){
            column(round(12/length(ftrs),0),align=ifelse(i == 1,"left",ifelse(i == length(ftrs),"right","middle")),
                   pickerInput(
                     inputId = session$ns(ftrs[[i]][[1]]), 
                     choices = ftrs[[i]][[3]],
                     options = list(
                       `actions-box` = TRUE,
                       `live-search` = TRUE,
                       `size` = 5,
                       `none-selected-text` = "Select Option"),
                     width = ifelse(length(ftrs) == 1,"50%",ifelse(length(ftrs) == 4,"90%","75%")),
                     multiple = TRUE,
                     selected = ftrs[[i]][[4]]))
          }
          else if(ftrs[[i]][[2]] == "groupbutton")
          {
            column(round(12/length(ftrs),0),align=ifelse(i == 1,"left",ifelse(i == length(ftrs),"right","middle")),
                   radioGroupButtons(
                     inputId = session$ns(ftrs[[i]][[1]]),
                     label = NULL,
                     choices = ftrs[[i]][[3]],
                     justified = FALSE,
                     status = "primary",
                     size = "xs",
                     selected = ftrs[[i]][[4]],
                     width = ifelse(length(ftrs) == 1,"50%",ifelse(length(ftrs) == 4,"90%","75%")),
                     checkIcon = list(
                       yes = icon("ok",
                                  lib = "glyphicon"))

                   ))
          }
        }))  
    })
}

boxplus_ftr_vals <- function(input,output,session,ftrs_name = NULL){
  ftr_list <- NULL
   ftrs_val <- reactive({
    for(i in 1:length(ftrs_name)){
      if(is.null(input[[ftrs_name[[i]]]])){val <- NA}else{val <- input[[ftrs_name[[i]]]]}
      ftr_list <- append(ftr_list,list(list(ftrs_name[[i]],val)))
    }
    ftr_list
  })
  return(ftrs_val())
}

boxplus_output <- function(input,output,session,info){

  output$main_body <- renderText({
    sprintf(paste0(info))
  })

}
```

I am getting the below error

```
Warning in paste0(info) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
Warning: Error in Vals: could not find function "Vals"
  98: paste0
  96: renderText [test.R#67]
  95: func
  82: origRenderFunc
  81: output$boxplus1-main_body
   1: runApp
```